# Условия использования иконок Material Design

Tags: material-design, иконки

Если резюмировать рулон лицензионного соглашения https://materialdesignicons.com/ в одно-два предложения, то каковы условия использования иконок Material Design?

P. S. Да, понимаю, что это не совсем программирование, но в то же время это и НЕ чистая юриспруденция. Я не думаю, что много юристов смыслят в веб-техноголиях, чтобы говорить с ними об этом - большинство из них про Material Design отродясь не слышали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*materialdesignicons.com*  - Material Design Icons [from the Community](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign)

> **License**
>
> Templates - [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/)
>
> Community Icons - [SIL Open Font License 1.1](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web)
>
> Google Material Design Icons - [Apache License 2.0](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/LICENSE)

[Здесь](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign/issues/2705#issuecomment-354047075) на вопрос о SVG [Templarian](https://github.com/Templarian) ссылается на [следующий источник](http://dev.materialdesignicons.com/license)

> There are many parts of this project and supporting projects covered
>   under various licenses.
>
> Material Design Icons Community   **SIL Open Font License 1.1**
>
> Material Design Icons Google  **Apache License 2.0 1**
>
> Material Design Icons SVG [**MIT License**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_MIT)
>
> Material Design Icons SCSS/CSS    **MIT License**
>
> Material Design Icons Site    **MIT License**
>
> Icon Templates    [**WTFPL**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL)
>
> Note: This does not cover third party plugins, components, etc that
>   are shown in the documentation. Please reference their GitHub pages for license
>   clarification.
>
> If anyone has time and wants to explain this all in more detail please
>   feel free to edit on GitHub and submit a pull request.
>
> *License has changed a couple times over the years, so this may vary*
>   *depending on version?*

---

**Google's official icon set.**

> **Open Source**
>
> The icons are available under the [Apache License](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_Apache) Version 2.0. We'd
>   love attribution in your app's "about" screen, but it's not required.
>   The only thing we ask is that you not re-sell these icons.

*Значки доступны под лицензией Apache версии 2.0. Нам понравится атрибуция на экране вашего приложения, но это не требуется. Единственное, что мы просим, это то, что вы не перепродаете эти значки.*

[Источник](https://material.io/icons/)

[Также](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)

> We have made these icons available for you to incorporate into your
>   products under the Apache License Version 2.0. Feel free to remix and
>   re-share these icons and documentation in your products.

*Мы сделали эти значки доступными для вас для включения в ваши продукты в соответствии с версией Apache версии 2.0. Не стесняйтесь пересобирать и переименовывать эти значки и документацию в своих продуктах.*